# $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x) \leq g'(x) ~\forall~ x \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x) \leq g(x) ~\forall~ x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**Here's a problem which I thought to be lacking an additional condition. So I imposed the condition and presented my solution. Please check whether it can be done *without* the additional condition. Thank you.**

> **The Problem :** Let $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Assume that $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x) \leq g'(x) ~\forall~ x \in \mathbb{R}$. To show that $f(x) \leq g(x) ~\forall~ x \geq 0$.

If we impose the condition that $g'(x) \neq 0 ~\forall~ x>0,$ then it is a quick consequence of [Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem).

For every $x > 0, \exists c \in (0,x)$ such that $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} \tag{1}$$

The right hand side of $(1)$ is $\leq 1$ because of given assumption. Coupled with the fact that $f(0)=g(0),$ we have the desired result. $\blacksquare$

**What can I do when $g'(x)=0$ at some points of $(0,\infty)??$**

Comment: Take $h=g-f$ and forget $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks! So we can use *ordinary* MVT on $h$ and get the job done!

Comment: @LiChunMin That's interesting. Can you please elaborate or give me some link where I can explore it?

Comment: With the hint of @LordSharktheUnknown note that $h^\prime$ has a sign.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309532/if-fx-le-gx-prove-fx-le-gx/2309539#2309539

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy version $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ has the following properties
$$h(0)=f(0)-g(0)=0$$
$$h'(x)=f'(x)-g'(x)\leq0 \tag{1}$$
$(1)$ makes $h(x)$ descending, thus for $\forall x \geq 0 \Rightarrow h(x) \leq h(0)=0$ and the result follows.

Comment: Hmmm ... this is actually a duplicate question, my fault for not reading the comments ...

Answer (score 0):

We don't need the mean value theorem here. You could just integrate the inequality. For any $t \ge 0$, we see $$f'(x) \le g'(x) \,\,\,\implies \,\,\, \int^t_0 f'(x) dx \le \int^t_0 g'(x) dx \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, f(t) - f(0) \le g(t) - g(0).$$ We could equally write this as $$f(t) \le g(t) - (g(0) - f(0)) \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, f(t) \le g(t)$$ since $g(0) - f(0) \ge 0$.

Comment: The derivative is not necessarily integrable.