# If $f′(x)≤g′(x)$ and they are not differentiable at $0$, does $f(x)≤g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f,g: [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ satisfy $f'(x)≤g'(x)$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$  and the functions are differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, does $f(x)≤g(x)$?

If $f,g$ were right-differentiable at $x=0$ then the statement would have been easily proven with the mean value theorem, but I'm not sure if it's true now that it isn't right-differentiable at $x=0$...

Comment: The mean value theorem does not require differentiability at the interval bounds, only continuity.

Comment: Are you assuming $f,g$ continuous on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @coffeemath Not necessarily.

Comment: @KantigShoter You may wish to assume that, given the answer of Volkov.

Comment: Note that your question is equivalent to its particular case $f=0.$ And it is then really unreasonable to not assume $g$ also continuous at $0.$ (Counterexample else: $g(0)=0,$ $g=-1$ on $(0,\infty)$.)

Comment: This answers your question [If $f'(x)\le g'(x)$, prove $f(x)\le g(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2309539/386889). (Of course, assuming your $f,g$ are continuous at $0$.)

Answer (score 4):

No. Take
$$
g(x)=x
$$
and
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }x=0;\\
1+x&\text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}
$$
The $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for $x>0$, $f(0)=g(0)=0$ but $f(x)=g(x)+1$ for $x>0$.

Comment: For a simpler counterexample, see my last comment above.